# Filter data where at least one row per set meets a condition using OData

Tags: sql, odata, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to filter data where at least one row per set meets a condition using OData from Azure Logic App.

I have such sample table

| mID | iID | resp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **null** | **null** | null |
| 111 | 123 | null |
| 111 | 124 | null |
| 111 | 125 | null |
| 111 | 126 | **yes** |
| **null** | **null** | null |
| 222 | 234 | null |
| 222 | **null** | null |
| 222 | 235 | null |
| 222 | 236 | null |
| 222 | 237 | **yes** |
| 333 | **null** | null |
| 333 | **null** | null |
| 333 | 345 | null |
| 333 | 346 | null |
| 333 | 347 | null |

and using OData filter I want only data as below

| mID | iID | resp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 333 | 345 | null |
| 333 | 346 | null |
| 333 | 347 | null |

where I filter out

- nulls from mID
- nulls from iID
- if at least one row have yes in resp column for mID and iID set

```
mID ne null and iID ne null
```

I tried `any` operator but with no success

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I achieved your requirement following the below process.
Firstly, I have used 2 Get Rows actions where one retrieves the values that doesn't contains null values using `mID ne null and iID ne null` and the other retrieves the rows that contains yes in resp column using `contains(resp,'yes')`.

[image]

Then I have initialized 2 variables, one to store mID's of the values from `Get rows (V2) yes` and other to store the final result. Below is the flow of the logic.

[image]

***RESULTS:***

[image]

Below is the schema of my Logic App

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@variables('array')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Condition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Append_to_array_variable_2": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "array",
                                    "value": "@items('For_each')"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "not": {
                                        "contains": [
                                            "@variables('YesMid')",
                                            "@items('For_each')?['mID']"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "If"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Get_rows_(V2)_null')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "For_each_2": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "YesMid",
                            "value": "@items('For_each_2')?['mID']"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Get_rows_(V2)_yes')?['value']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Get_rows_(V2)_null": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[Samp]'))}/items",
                    "queries": {
                        "$filter": "mID ne null and iID ne null"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Get_rows_(V2)_yes": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[Samp]'))}/items",
                    "queries": {
                        "$filter": "contains(resp,'yes')"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_rows_(V2)_null": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "YesMid",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_rows_(V2)_yes": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "array",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "sql": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SUBID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql",
                    "connectionName": "sql",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SUBID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/sql"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @SwethaKandikonda, thank you a lot, looks like an only solution, as OData query in Logic App is limited, but unfortunately, I cannot replicate your results. I see that you used two 'For Each' loops, but in schema only one, could you please edit and explain a bit more?

Comment: @adam_szmyt Apologies on that part, I have updated my answer